# python virtualenv unable to create process

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

this error always comes when I try to install any package on my virtual environment.
I only have one python version on my device.

things I tried to do :

- reinstall python and remove the old one and upgrade my pip version.
- **LongPathsEnabled** to 1 , and **Enable NTFS long paths** to 1.

Also no problem when I install on my installed python but when I try to install on my virtualenv it doesn't work.

[image: error log]

Comment: @CaptainCaveman i don't think he calling py executable himself, looks like he running pip install as just someone would do.

Comment: yes I am trying to "pip install numpy" any package
I also copied an environment from a friend and worked fine. But I can't freeze my project I need to solve this problem.

Comment: Ah, I see, my mistake. What happens if you just type 'python' at the cmd prompt?

Comment: I'm curious if your python interpreter is where you think it is.

Comment: it works fine ant the python interpreter opens when i command python.

Comment: ok, so once you are in the interpreter, run pip install numpy. What happens if you run 'pip' at the cmd prompt?

Comment: it works in the interpreter. but never works in the virtual env

Comment: can you run any python script (with no module dependencies) in the virtual env?

Comment: it gives me the same error